# Convert 32SC1 to CV_8U

Tags: c++, opencv, bit

I am using kmeans clustering function in OpenCV. The returned labels has type CV_32SC1, and since they are integers (1,2,3,4 representing the labels) I convert it to CV_8U:

lev.convertTo(lev, CV_8U)

After the conversion it converts to totally different numbers:

```
33686018
33686018
33686018
33686018
33686018
33686018
```

Can someone explain this phenomenon for me? I thought a 2 in CV_8U should be kept the same as in CV_32SC1?

Answer (score 2):

CV_8U matrix cannot contain these integer values (33686018). What code did you use to check the contents of the result matrix? You may be incorrectly reading uchar values from the matrix.

The conversion worked fine for me. This is my test code:

```
// declare CV_32SC1 matrix
Mat A(3,3,CV_32SC1);

// initialize A with random numbers
randu(A, Scalar(0), Scalar(100));  
cout << "original A = " << A << endl;

// convert A to CV_8U
A.convertTo(A, CV_8U);
// output the result
cout << "after converting A = " << A << endl;

// if you want to print out a single pixel of A, say at location (0,0)
int pixel = static_cast<int>(A.at<uchar>(0,0));
cout << "pixel at A(0,0) = " << pixel << endl;
```